# Armor stacking and the Armorer Artificer

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, unearthed-arcana, artificer

If I'm a [Armorer Artificer](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020-Subclasses03_0224.pdf) with my power armor in Infiltrator Mode (the armor’s weight is negligible, and it's formfitting and wearable under clothing) and infused with the Enhanced Defense infusion (+1 or +2 to AC depending upon level), can I then don a +3 set of plate armor and if I do what's my AC?

Would other infusions from the under-armor work normally?

Comment: You mean don a set of armor *over* your regular armor?

Comment: @Erik Yes, I wondered if the +x to AC bonuses can only be applied to their respective armors or if they stack like normal +x to AC bonuses from other items (i.e. ring of protection and cloak of protection)

Comment: This question arises from the UA version of the Armorer.  The official version (published in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything after this question was asked) has removed the description that the infiltrator model is "formfitting and wearable under clothing," so you can no longer contemplate wearing it under other armor.  Therefore possible armor stacking is no longer a concern.

Answer (score 14):

Armor changes how AC is calculated. If you have multiple ways to calculate AC, you [choose which one you want to use](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-january-2016). If you have Unarmored Defence, Mage Armor and Barkskin, you only benefit from one of those.

So, even if you manage to don both armors, you will have to choose which one to actually use.

Comment: I'm asking about the ac bonus attached to the armor, not the armor's ac.

Comment: @Cellheim: The +3 bonus of +3 armor is part of the armor's AC calculation.

Comment: @V2Blast Why isn't it like the +1 to ac effect from a ring of protection? Is it said anywhere that it isn't?

Comment: @V2Blast I've always assumed that to be true too, but looking into it, is it actually spelt out explicitly anywhere? Choosing from different methods of caluclating your base AC aside (which is very clear), the AC bonus gained from a +1 suit of armor is phrased in pretty much exactly the same way as the bonus from a Ring of Protection.

Comment: @V2Blast Of course, until now it hasn't been an issue because you couldn't wear more than one suit of armor, and all the existing alternative methods of calculating AC have the explicit prerequisite of being unarmored. The 'Second Skin' feature is therefore a bit of spanner in the works.

Answer (score 9):

## Ask your DM about wearing multiple items of the same kind

The problem arises because of how magical armour words it bonus:

> You have a +1 bonus to AC while wearing this armor.

So, wearing multiple armours with such a bonus should let them stack. However, wearing multiple items of the same type is generally not possible (depending on DM's common sense; emphasis added to quotation):

> Multiple Items of the Same Kind
>   Use common sense to determine whether more than one of a given kind of magic item can be worn. A character can't normally wear more than one pair of footwear, one pair of gloves or gauntlets, one pair of bracers, *one suit of armor*, one item of head wear, and one cloak. You can make exceptions; a character might be able to wear a circlet under a helmet, for example, or be able to layer two cloaks.
>
> — *Dungeon Master's Guide*, p. 141

Whether the alterations to your power armour is sufficient to make it wearable underneath other armour in such a fashion that you can benefit from both is explicitly left to your DM's common sense.

I wouldn't be surprised if they used their common sense to say the magical improvement to the armour makes the AC when using that armour for AC calculation X higher, and that the wording simply assumes you won't be wearing multiple suits (because that's silly).

So, to summarize, ask your DM because you are dealing with the interaction between playtest material and magic items (which often need a little DM adjudication).

Comment: Why is wearing something light and able to be worn under clothing silly to wear with normal armor? Wouldn't this be like wearing a circlet under a helmet?

Comment: I meant that as wearing two suits of normal armour (which is the possible option there that the wording is assuming)

Comment: @NomadMaker These details are handwaved in D&D, but you already need to wear a layer under any heavy armor, a layer designed for specifically for that purpose, part of the armor basically. Otherwise there will be chafing, it won't protect against blows properly, etc. Unless your power armor is specificlally designed for the purpose, presumably sacrificing other features, using it under a plate mail would break it, break the plate mail and stop you from moving properly in battle. Just try it yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir I have. I was a member of Markland (similar to the SCA) while in college. Anything comfortable enough to fit under normal clothing would fit under heavy armor. Of course, the heat buildup might be even worse. And I wouldn't want to clean it after a good summer fight. But I don't think that the armors would break each other.

Answer (score 7):

## You can only benefit from one type of armor at a time

if you were somehow able to wear two suits of armor at the same time, only 1 calculation for your AC can be used, so I would assume you pick the higher one 
I would also like to point out that under the power armor ability

> The armor continues to be power armor until you doff it, **you don another suit of armor**, or you die.

So donning a suit of armor over top of your power armor is going to cause your power armor to not function.

To clarify on your bounty. **The magical bonus granted by magic armor is included as part of the armors ac calculation.**

For example breastplate is 15+dex(max 2)

A +3 breastplate is 18+dex(max 2)

+3 plate armor is 21

DMG pg. 140-141

> Using a magic item’s properties might mean wearing or wielding it. **A magic item meant to be worn must be donned in the intended fashion**: boots go on the feet, gloves on the hands, hats and helmets on the head, and rings on the finger. Magic armor must be donned, a Shield strapped to the arm, a cloak fastened about the shoulders. A weapon must be held.

and

> **Use Common sense to determine whether more than one of a given kind of magic item can be worn.** A character can’t normally wear more than one pair of footwear, one pair of gloves or gauntlets, one pair of bracers, **one suit of armor**, one item of headwear, and one cloak. You can make exceptions; a character might be able to wear a circlet under a helmet, for example, or to layer two cloaks.

Armor isn't intended to be layered therefor stacking magic armors doesn't provide magical benifit.

Comment: Why would my power suit infusions aside from the one that boosts AC cease to function?  Also where does it say that the AC bonus on armor is counted as part of the armor's base AC when the AC bonus is phrased exactly the same as a ring of protection? It's also listed as a modifier in the item listing separate from the AC section.

Comment: I think there is another very important point which can be found from the quote Shinn gives: If the power armour stops being power armour, does it also negate the second skin benefit of the power armour? If so, the entire question becomes moot because that would make it *impossible* to wear another suit of armour over the Infiltrator Mode power armour.

Comment: @cellheim You keep restating that point. Rather than debating each answer, it's more than okay for you to submit your own answer. So far, all answers have basically come to the same conclusion, and you have challenged all of them. Put up your viewpoint and see if others accept it.

Comment: @Cellheim I added more to my answer for clarification. also to answer your new question here in the comment...Your power armor would cease to function if you don another armor because the class feature says it does. I already quoted the class feature that says "The armor continues to be power armor until you doff it, you don another suit of armor, or you die." All the other class features that talk about power armor require your power armor to still be power armor.

Answer (score 1):

The armor continues to be power armor until you doff it, you don another suit of armor, or you die.

If you put a suit of armor on over the infiltrator armor, it no long is infiltrator armor, as it is no longer power armor, so it could no longer be worn under another suit of armor.